# Binding PlayerView with SimpleExoPlayer from a service

Tags: android, service, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, bindservice

I have implemented a Service to run the audio in background which runs perfectly but I am unable to get the instance of the SimpleExoPlayer from the service to the activity to update the UI and also the Audio plays twice in the background if I exit and reopen the activity.

**AudioPlayerService**

```
public class AudioPlayerService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private Item item;
    private PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(null);
        player.release();
        player = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
    enter code here
    public SimpleExoPlayer getplayerInstance() {
        return player;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (b != null) {
            item = b.getParcelable(AppConstants.ITEM_KEY);
        }
        startPlayer();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startPlayer() {
        final Context context = this;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getUrl());
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, new DefaultTrackSelector());
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                Util.getUserAgent(context, getString(R.string.app_name)));
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        playerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(context, AppConstants.PLAYBACK_CHANNEL_ID,
                R.string.playback_channel_name,
                AppConstants.PLAYBACK_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
                        return item.getTitle();
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayerActivity.class);
                        Bundle serviceBundle = new Bundle();
                        serviceBundle.putParcelable(AppConstants.ITEM_KEY, item);
                        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY, serviceBundle);
                        return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public String getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
                        return item.getSummary();
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
                        return item.getBitmap();
                    }
                }
        );
        playerNotificationManager.setNotificationListener(new PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNotificationStarted(int notificationId, Notification notification) {
                startForeground(notificationId, notification);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNotificationCancelled(int notificationId) {
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
        playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public AudioPlayerService getService() {
            return AudioPlayerService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my activity where I am starting the service and binding to it. I have to pass the Item object in-order the service to run, if I don't pass the data using the intent the service will crash so I can't do startService() in the service itself I have to start in the activity I guess.

**PlayerActivity**

```
public class PlayerActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.video_view)
    PlayerView mPlayerView;
    @BindView(R.id.tvTitle)
    TextView mTvTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.tvSummary)
    TextView mTvSummary;
    @BindView(R.id.ivThumbnail)
    ImageView mIvThumb;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private String mURL, mTitle, mSummary, mImage;
    private AudioPlayerService mService;
    private boolean mBound = false;
    private Intent intent;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            AudioPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (AudioPlayerService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {


mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.activity_player);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (b != null) {
            Item item = b.getParcelable(AppConstants.ITEM_KEY);
            mURL = item.getUrl();
            mImage = item.getImage();
            mTitle = item.getTitle();
            mSummary = item.getSummary();
            intent = new Intent(this, AudioPlayerService.class);
            Bundle serviceBundle = new Bundle();
            serviceBundle.putParcelable(AppConstants.ITEM_KEY, item);
            intent.putExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY, serviceBundle);
            Util.startForegroundService(this, intent);

        }
    }

    private void initializePlayer() {
        if (player == null && !mURL.isEmpty() && mBound) {
            player = mService.getplayerInstance();
            mPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
            mPlayerView.setControllerHideOnTouch(false);
            mPlayerView.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(10800000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        initializePlayer();
        setUI();
    }

    private void setUI() {
        mTvTitle.setText(mTitle);
        mTvSummary.setText(mSummary);
        GlideApp.with(this)
                .load(mImage)
                .placeholder(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(mIvThumb);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
        releasePlayer();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.player_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.share_podcast:
                //Logic for Share
                return true;
            case R.id.download_podcast:
                //Logic for download
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onToolBarSetUp(Toolbar toolbar, ActionBar actionBar) {
        TextView tvHeader = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tvClassName);
        tvHeader.setText(R.string.app_name);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
    }
}
```

I have tried everything I know but I'm unable to move forward because of this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So after a lot of research I was able to resolve this using the bound service and getting the SimpleExoPlayer instance from the service and set the Player view to always show up using the following method.

```
mPlayerView.showController()
```

After all the modification and setup it takes only two classes to achieve background audio playback with notification control, one is the activity and the other is the service using the latest exoplayer release.

**PlayerActivity**

```
    public class PlayerActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.video_view)
    PlayerView mPlayerView;
    @BindView(R.id.tvTitle)
    TextView mTvTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.tvSummary)
    TextView mTvSummary;
    @BindView(R.id.ivThumbnail)
    ImageView mIvThumb;
    private String mUrl, mTitle, mSummary, mImage;
    private AudioPlayerService mService;
    private Intent intent;
    private String shareableLink;
    private boolean mBound = false;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            AudioPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (AudioPlayerService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
            initializePlayer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.activity_player);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (b != null) {
            Item item = b.getParcelable(AppConstants.ITEM_KEY);
            shareableLink = b.getString(AppConstants.SHARE_KEY);
            mImage = item.getImage();
            mUrl = item.getUrl();
            mTitle = item.getTitle();
            mSummary = item.getSummary();
            intent = new Intent(this, AudioPlayerService.class);
            Bundle serviceBundle = new Bundle();
            serviceBundle.putParcelable(AppConstants.ITEM_KEY, item);
            intent.putExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY, serviceBundle);
            Util.startForegroundService(this, intent);
            mPlayerView.setUseController(true);
            mPlayerView.showController();
            mPlayerView.setControllerAutoShow(true);
            mPlayerView.setControllerHideOnTouch(false);
        }
    }

    private void initializePlayer() {
        if (mBound) {
            SimpleExoPlayer player = mService.getplayerInstance();
            mPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        initializePlayer();
        setUI();
    }

    private void setUI() {
        mTvTitle.setText(mTitle);
        mTvSummary.setText(mSummary);
        GlideApp.with(this)
                .load(mImage)
                .placeholder(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(mIvThumb);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.player_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.share_podcast:
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mTitle);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mTitle + "\n\n" + shareableLink);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_text)));
                return true;
            case R.id.download_podcast:
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(mUrl);
                ProgressiveDownloadAction progressiveDownloadAction
                        = new ProgressiveDownloadAction(uri, false, null, null);
                AudioDownloadService.startWithAction(PlayerActivity.this, AudioDownloadService.class,
                        progressiveDownloadAction, false);
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onToolBarSetUp(Toolbar toolbar, ActionBar actionBar) {
        TextView tvHeader = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tvClassName);
        tvHeader.setText(R.string.app_name);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
    }
}
```

**AudioPlayerService**

```
    public class AudioPlayerService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private Item item;
    private PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        releasePlayer();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(null);
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public SimpleExoPlayer getplayerInstance() {
        if (player == null) {
            startPlayer();
        }
        return player;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //releasePlayer();
        Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (b != null) {
            item = b.getParcelable(AppConstants.ITEM_KEY);
        }
        if (player == null) {
            startPlayer();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startPlayer() {
        final Context context = this;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getUrl());
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, new DefaultTrackSelector());
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                Util.getUserAgent(context, getString(R.string.app_name)));
        CacheDataSourceFactory cacheDataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(
                DownloadUtil.getCache(context),
                dataSourceFactory,
                CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR);
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        playerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(context, AppConstants.PLAYBACK_CHANNEL_ID,
                R.string.playback_channel_name,
                AppConstants.PLAYBACK_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
                        return item.getTitle();
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayerActivity.class);
                        Bundle serviceBundle = new Bundle();
                        serviceBundle.putParcelable(AppConstants.ITEM_KEY, item);
                        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY, serviceBundle);
                        return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public String getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
                        return item.getSummary();
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
        );
        playerNotificationManager.setNotificationListener(new PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNotificationStarted(int notificationId, Notification notification) {
                startForeground(notificationId, notification);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNotificationCancelled(int notificationId) {
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
        playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public AudioPlayerService getService() {
            return AudioPlayerService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How come you are using `bindService` to initiate the Foreground Service rather than _ExoPlayer's_ `Util.startForegroundService`?

Comment: Thanks! This saved me a lot of time. Also, `showController()` fixed it for me alone. I tested each method alone and together and have found the additional methods are not required.

Comment: Hii there I am using the logic you have provided but I am not able to control play pause next buttons, it doesn't sync with my service. I am using pic in pic mode it is showing controller properly if I am in the picture in picture mode , so the issue with ui though ,can u suggest what can be done?

Comment: @Akram Hussian : Can i get code for AppConstants and Item class?

Comment: @user1090751 Sure, I made it opensource. You can find the code here: https://github.com/Akramhussain4/podcast-app. Feel free to make a pull request if you add something new!

Comment: @AkramHussain I want the code samples on java not kotlin. Do you have it for Java?

Comment: @user1090751 Unfortunately, I don't. I converted the project to Kotlin.