# Passing ExoPlayer instance from activity to binded service?

Tags: service, notifications, instance, bind, exoplayer

I'm trying to make a Video Player using ExoPlayer that can also work in the background and you can control it through the notification. I already created the ExoPlayer and the ForeGround Service for the notification and i binded them. At the moment it works as intended, the only problem is that i don't want the activity player to stop working when i close the notification. This happens because at the moment i'm creating the ExoPlayer instance in the service and then i pass the instance to the Activity, so when i close the notification the instance gets lost. Is there a way to initialize the player instance in the Activity and then pass that instance to the service so i can still control the video from the notification without risking to lose the instance once the notification is closed?

I'm pretty new to android and this is the first time that i'm binding a service to an activity so i don't really know how to do it. I tried searching on Google but that didn't help either.

This is the Activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        playerView=findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        intent=new Intent(this,AudioPlayerService.class);

        //here i will add the url that needs to be loaded 
        //but at the moment this is just a draft

        Util.startForegroundService(this,intent);
        playerView.setUseController(true);
        //playerView.showController();
        playerView.setControllerAutoShow(true);
        playerView.setControllerHideOnTouch(true);
    }


    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            AudioPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (AudioPlayerService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
            initializePlayer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        initializePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }


    private void initializePlayer() {
        if (mBound) {
            SimpleExoPlayer player = mService.getplayerInstance();
            playerView.setPlayer(player);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Service

```
@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public SimpleExoPlayer getplayerInstance() {
        if (player == null) {
            startPlayer();
        }
        return player;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public AudioPlayerService getService() {
            return AudioPlayerService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        final Context context=this;
    }

    private void startPlayer() {
        final Context context = this;
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, new DefaultTrackSelector());
        ProgressiveMediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("NotificationSync", 10000, 10000, true))
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        playerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(context, "1",
                R.string.app_name,
                2,
                new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
                        return "title";
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public String getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
                        return "text";
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
                        return null;
                    }

                }, new PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNotificationCancelled(int notificationId, boolean dismissedByUser) {
                        stopSelf();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNotificationPosted(int notificationId, Notification notification, boolean ongoing) {
                        mNotification = notification;
                        mNotificationId = notificationId;
                        if (ongoing) {
                            startForeground(notificationId, notification);
                        }
                    }

                }
        );
        playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseStopAction(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        releasePlayer();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (player == null) {

        //here i will get all the data from the intent that came from the 
        //activity (title,text,url...)

            startPlayer();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }


}
```

In the end all i want to achieve is a video player that you start in the activity and also works/can be controlled through a notification without interruption when i go from activity->background and background->activity. If there are other ways to achieve this i'm open to try.

Comment: In the end i did it the other way following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52680590/11731416)